# Calculating covariance of a jointly distributed probability function- solution verification

Tags: probability, statistics, solution-verification

> Let $X$ denote the size of a surgical claim and let $Y$ denote the size of the associated $2$
> hospital claim. An actuary is using a model in which $E(X) = 5$, $E(X ) = 27.4, E(Y) = 7, 2
> E(Y ) = 51.4$, and $Var(X+Y) = 8$. Let $C_1 = X+Y$ denote the size of the combined claims before the application of a $20\%$ surcharge on the hospital portion of the claim, and let $C_2$ denote the size of the combined claims after the application of that surcharge.
> Calculate $Cov(C1, C2)$.

My attempt:

Note that $C_2 = 1.2 C_1$, so $$Cov(C_1, C_2) = Cov(C_1, 1.2C_1) = E(C_1\cdot 1.2C_1) - E[C_1] \cdot E[1.2C_1]$$
$$ = 1.2 E[C_1^2] - 1.2 \{E[C_1]^2\} = 1.2 \left\{E[C_1^2] - E[C_1]^2\right\} = 1.2 Var[C_1] = 1.2 Var(X+Y) =$$
$$ 1.2 \times 8 = 9.6$$

This is not correct. Can someone please point out why that is?

Comment: $C_2=1.2C_1$ how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$C_2\ne 1.2C_2$

The question says **"20% surcharge on the hospital portion of the claim"**

That is $20 $ % of $Y = 0.2Y$

Then it says
**" C2 denote the size of the combined claims after the application of that surcharge"**
Combined claim is addition of $C_1+0.2Y$

so

$C_2=X+Y+0.2Y=X+1.2Y$

$COV(C1, C2) = COV(X+Y, X+1.2Y ) = COV(X, X)+COV(X, 1.2Y )+COV(Y, X)+COV(Y, 1.2Y )$

> $COV(X_1+X_2,X_1+X_2)=COV(X_1,X_1)+COV(X_1,X_2)+COV(X_2,X_1)+COV(X_2,X_2)$

> $COV(aX_1,bX_2)=abCOV(X_1,X_2)$

> $COV(X,X)=V(X)$

$Var X + 1.2 COV(X, Y ) + COV(X, Y ) + 1.2 V(Y) = Var X + 2.2 COV(X, Y ) + 1.2 V(Y)$

Can you do next?

Comment: Got it, thanks.

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson Do you have similar types of questions(Expectation, Mixed distributions, etc) as PDF? I want to practice them. If you could arrange for me that will be a great help.

Comment: SOA's entire set of practice problems is available for free on the web is you just do a Google search for it.